# Why is my response error different from the one caught by error interceptor?

Tags: angular, error-handling, httpresponse

I have this API that throws an exception if the file size to be downloaded exceeds the max set.

```
@GET
    @Path("files")
    public Response getFile(@QueryParam("filePath") String filePath) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);

        long fileSizeKb = Math.max(file.length() / 1024, 1);

        if (fileSizeKb > APIServerProperties.MAX_DOWNLOADABLE_FILE_SIZE_KB) {
            String msg = MessageBundle.getMessage(MessageKeys.ERR_FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED, String.valueOf(fileSizeKb),
                    String.valueOf(APIServerProperties.MAX_DOWNLOADABLE_FILE_SIZE_KB));
            System.out.println("msg: " + msg);
            throw new GeneralException(msg,
                    new FileSizeLimitExceededException(msg, fileSizeKb, APIServerProperties.MAX_DOWNLOADABLE_FILE_SIZE_KB));
        }

        // Read file content into byte array
        byte[] fileBytes = readFileContent(file);

        return Response.ok(fileBytes).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName()).build();
    }
```

It is being called by this angular function:

```
downloadFile(filePath: string) {
    this.migrationService.getFile(filePath).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        const fileContent: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(response);
        const fileContentStr = new TextDecoder().decode(fileContent);

        const forwardSplit = filePath.split("/");
        const backwardSplit = forwardSplit[forwardSplit.length - 1].split("\\");
        let fileName = backwardSplit[backwardSplit.length - 1];

        const element = document.createElement("a");
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/cvs;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContentStr)
        );
        element.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      },
    });
  }
```

All good so far. When I force the error, I get this as a response. This is what I need so I can display it properly.
[image]

However, this is what I see in the console logs from the **downloadFile** function.
[image]

Why am I not getting the response object and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492093/how-to-get-the-error-data-when-using-responsetype-as-arraybuffer-for-post-method) which is quite similar to the problem I was having. It gave me an idea of what I had to do.

I updated my `downloadFile` function's error handling. I processed the arrayBuffer similar to when I am reading the file content. This time, passing in the error object.

```
downloadFile(filePath: string) {
    this.migrationService.getFile(filePath).subscribe({
      next: (response) => {
        const fileContent: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(response);
        const fileContentStr = new TextDecoder().decode(fileContent);
        const forwardSplit = filePath.split("/");
        const backwardSplit = forwardSplit[forwardSplit.length - 1].split("\\");
        let fileName = backwardSplit[backwardSplit.length - 1];
        const element = document.createElement("a");
        element.setAttribute(
          "href",
          "data:text/cvs;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContentStr)
        );
        element.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        element.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        const buffer = new Uint8Array(err.error);
        const bufferStr = new TextDecoder().decode(buffer);
        const errorResponse = JSON.parse(bufferStr);
        const config = new MatDialogConfig();
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorMessageComponent, config);
        this.dialogRef.componentInstance.msgObj = {
          errorMessage: errorResponse.statusText,
        };
      },
    });
  }
```